# (Author Date) inline citations vs anonymous references with ISO 690

Tags: citation-style

I am trying to use the the [Czech language ISO 690 style](https://github.com/citation-style-language/styles/blob/master/iso690-author-date-cs.csl) in the (Author Year) variant. However, citing anonymous references seems unsatisfactory. I am getting just "(ANON. 2016)". That gives almost zero identification information.

How do people deal with this?

I was thinking of [modifying the style](https://gist.github.com/wilx/0a96809a23d71762b4fb#file-iso690-author-date-czech-wilx-xml) and using ("Title" Year) instead, when neither author nor editor nor translator nor interviewer is available.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

ISO 690 is rather unambiguous about this (section 5.6. "Anonymous works"):

> For  anonymous  works  cited  by  the  name  and  date  system  (see 
>   A.2),  “Anon”  may  be  used  instead  of  a creator's name. For
>   anonymous works cited by the numeric system (see A.3) or running notes
>   (see A.4), the title may be treated as the first element. If the
>   creator's name is known, it may be supplied.

If your publication venue requires you to use ISO 690 with name-date, you really don't have any choice here. After all, consistency is why journals etc. require you to follow a citation/publication style.

---

As per appendix A.2, you can distinguish different anonymous works from the same year by appending letters: (Anon., 2016a) vs. (Anon., 2016b). This is standard in Harvard style derivatives.